# Dynamic typed languages and the pain of refactoring and reading code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, dynamic-typing

I am working on a angular and nodejs project. Many functions are written like this

**DESIGN 1**

```
function foo(device, user){
 ...
}
```

Now I don't know what device is, nor user. But I guess that's just the thing about dynamic typed languages, you have to debug each object to know what it is. Ok i can live with that, it makes maintenance super slow but I guess you are quicker writing the initial app.

Now the second problem I face, I look at the function and see the coder is only using

`device.baz` and `user.bar`

now he could have written the function just like

**DESIGN 2**

```
function foo(baz, bar){
 ...
}
```

making it easier for me to see what is actually used.
Another pitfall I guess of dynamic typing? `foo(device, user)` is probably better, because in dynamic typing, refactoring is impossible. E.g. if he finds out he wants to use `device.beta` in his function, he would be in trouble. But with the unreadable approach, he has all the freedom he wants.

So my question: is Design 1 superior to design 2 in real world scenarios?

Well and please "CLOSEVOTE!!!! there is no answer to this!!!"

please, there is an answer, there is clearly one approach that has been proven to be ways better than another one.

Comment: The answer is it depends. There is no one approach that works well in all situations.

Comment: well sometimes it is better to write not object oriented. I am sure you can always come up with a scenario that makes sense for something. But I am not talking about some scenarios that only, and only, seem feasible to an intellectual.

Comment: Yes, I'm not talking about scenarios that only seem feasible to an intellectual.

Comment: why you think, that refactoring impossilbe here?

Comment: @slebetman well which scenarios then? the reason I post, is I don't know which to use. "It depends" helps me exactly 0

Comment: @Grundy how do you easily find ALL references to said function? lets call the function `get()`

Comment: _easily find_ not same as _impossible_ i think :-)

Comment: @Grundy well, it is pretty close to impossible refactoring a function with a name that is common in a big project. I think calling it impossible is fine.

Comment: nope, i think you do _big project_ not in simple notepad, but with some ide, linters, and etc, so many functions can be automated.

Comment: To find all references to a function you'd use a tool like grasp. There are already tools that are even more powerful like Komodo IDE that use a javascript interpreter to parse your code.

Comment: now many IDE provide function that helps work with dynamic languages like javascript, and also provide functions for refactoring.

Comment: Sounds like someone loves `.net` a bit too much. Refactoring becomes troublesome when you have poor design. Your JavaScript should be modular and componentalised (that's probably not a real word) with set namespaces and well documented external API's for each module. If you have single monolith JavaScript files where just just keep throwing your methods in and use your methods everywhere then your bound for trouble. If you follow any modular design, commonJs new ES6 import you know exactly what is used where and exactly what to change.

Comment: @ste2425 so you are saying refactoring is easy and straight forward in dynamically typed languages. So basically, design 2 is always the answer?

Comment: @ste2425 to your sidepunch to `.net` : I am a bit tired of reading code that reads like this `whatisThis.then(function(whatisthat){noclue = whatisthat.dowhat(); return noclue.bizar})`

Comment: As say @slebetman, answer is it depends. You can't use one approach in all cases.

Comment: @Toskan im am not saying either as without knowing the rest of your application design you can't say. If your JavaScript application is built correctly following modern standards then im saying functions should work with exactly what they need. They should have singular purposes and should have specific data to serve that purpose. They shouldn't need huge objects to serve multiple tasks. You then chain them to achieve more complex functionality without loosing the specific purpose of each link in the chain. Follow functional practices, rather than one monolith object that tries to rule all.

Comment: Don't forget that tests are your best friends when refactoring code without the help of automated tools.

Also, TypeScript.